# Simple Injector instance is requested outside the context of an active (async scope) scope

Tags: vb.net, simple-injector

I'm trying to inject my IAuthorizationRepository into my VB Web App using SimpleInjector.

```
Public Class IdentityPackage
    Implements IPackage
    Public Sub RegisterServices(container As Container) Implements IPackage.RegisterServices
        container.Register(Of IUserStore(Of User, Integer), UserStore)(Lifestyle.Scoped)
        container.Register(Of IAuthorizationRepository, AuthorizationRepository)(Lifestyle.Scoped)
        container.Register(Of ISession, Session)()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's my startup.

```
Public Partial Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
        Dim container = ConfigureSimpleInjector(app)
        Dim config = New HttpConfiguration() With {
            .DependencyResolver = New SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container)
        }

        ConfigureOAuth(app, container)

        WebApiConfig.Register(config)
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
        app.UseWebApi(config)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here's my ConfigureOAuth.

```
Public Sub ConfigureOAuth(app As IAppBuilder, container As Container)
    Dim authRepositoryFactory As Func(Of IAuthorizationRepository) = container.GetInstance(Of IAuthorizationRepository)

    Dim authorizationOptions = New OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() With {
        .AllowInsecureHttp = True,
        .TokenEndpointPath = New PathString("/api/token"),
        .AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4),
        .Provider = New AuthorizationServerProvider(authRepositoryFactory)
    }

    ' Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(authorizationOptions)
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(New OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions())
End Sub
```

When it gets to the first line under `ConfigureOAuth`, it throws the error `The AuthorizationRepository is registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.`

The strange thing is that I'm converting an existing, and fully functional C# project into VB, and this is the VB equivalent of the codebase in C#, but the C# code does not have this problem. This makes me feel like the issue lies in how VB handles the code, as opposed to C#, but I don't see how that could be the case with this example. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

The following is my stack trace:

```
[ActivationException: The AuthorizationRepository is registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.]
   SimpleInjector.Scope.GetScopelessInstance(ScopedRegistration`1 registration) +168
   SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance(ScopedRegistration`1 registration, Scope scope) +52
   SimpleInjector.Advanced.Internal.LazyScopedRegistration`1.GetInstance(Scope scope) +158
   lambda_method(Closure ) +223
   SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance() +32
   SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance() +235
   SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceForRootType() +154
   SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance() +146
   ClientWebAppVB.Api.Startup.ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, Container container) in C:\Projects\TEST\ClientWebAppVB\ClientWebAppVB.Api\App_Start\OAuthConfig.vb:10
   ClientWebAppVB.Api.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in C:\Projects\TEST\ClientWebAppVB\ClientWebAppVB.Api\Startup.vb:15

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +160
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +101
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass12.<MakeDelegate>b__b(IAppBuilder builder) +66
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadImplementation>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +123
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InitializeBlueprint>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +71
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +462
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +40
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +70
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +536
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10044576
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Lesson of the day: don't use VB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The strange thing is that I'm converting an existing, and fully functional C# project into VB, and this is the VB equivalent of the codebase in C#, but the C# code does not have this problem

Well this is actually not the equivalent of the c# version. And unless you changed `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` settings I'm pretty sure the code you show does not even compile. Or in your real code you omitted the As `Func(Of IAuthorizationRepository)` clause.

In c# this two lines are 2 totally different things:

```cs
// create a delegate
Func<IAuthorizationRepository> authRepositoryFactory = 
                        container.GetInstance<IAuthorizationRepository>;
// and directly call a delegate or method
Func<IAuthorizationRepository> authRepositoryFactory = 
                        container.GetInstance<IAuthorizationRepository>();
```

And here the second line does not compile. This line returns `IAuthorizationRepository` and therefore is not assignable to `Func<IAuthorizationRepository>`.

In Vb.Net however the following lines are exactly the same. The braces of a method call are totally optional.

```vb
' Directly call the method
Dim authRepositoryFactory = container.GetInstance(Of IAuthorizationRepository)
' And directy call the method
Dim authRepositoryFactory = container.GetInstance(Of IAuthorizationRepository)()
```

If you hover over `authRepositoryFactory` you'll see that the inferred type is `IAuthorizationRepository` for both lines.

To create a delegate instead of directly invoking it in VB you need to use the [`AddressOf` Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addressof-operator)

```vb
Dim authRepositoryFactory = New Func(Of IAuthorizationRepository)(
              AddressOf container.GetInstance(Of IAuthorizationRepository))

'or
Dim authRepositoryFactory As Func(Of IAuthorizationRepository) =
              AddressOf container.GetInstance(Of IAuthorizationRepository)
```

If you would hover over `authRepositoryFactory` you'll see this is actually a `Func (Of IAuthorizationRepository)`

Comment: Ah god damn it. Thank you. I totally missed that.